# Call C++ code from Powershell using DLLImport

Tags: powershell

Below is the C# code which i used to get the credentials. It is successful.

```
class ClassName
{
    [DllImport("BinaryName.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCredentials")]
    static extern int GetCredentials(StringBuilder sbUser, StringBuilder sbPassword, string sKey);

static bool MethodName()
{
    int iSuccess = 0;
    StringBuilder sUser = new StringBuilder(256);
    StringBuilder sPwd = new StringBuilder(256);

    iSuccess = GetCredentials(sUser, sPwd, "KeyValue");
}
```

}

Below is the powershell code to mimic the above c# code to get the credential

```
$args1 = ""
$args2 = ""
$args3 = "KeyValue"
$GetCredentials = @'
[DllImport("C:\\Path\\BinaryName.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCredentials", ExactSpelling=false)]
public static extern int GetCredentials([out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] out String $args1, [out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] out String $args2, [In] String $args3);
'@
$typeFunc = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $GetCredentials -Name "GetCredentials" -PassThru -Namespace System.Runtime.InteropServices
$ret = $typeFunc::GetCredentials($args1, $args2, $args3)
```

Getting below error message. Please help me

```
Add-Type : c:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\bzhzifxk\bzhzifxk.0.cs(9) : Unexpected character '$'
c:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\bzhzifxk\bzhzifxk.0.cs(8) :     [DllImport("C:\\Path\\BinaryName.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCredentials", ExactSpelling=false)]
c:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\bzhzifxk\bzhzifxk.0.cs(9) : >>> public static extern int GetCredentials([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]StringBuilder $args1, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]StringBuilder $args2, 
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]String $args3);
c:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\bzhzifxk\bzhzifxk.0.cs(10) : 
At line:8 char:13
+ $typeFunc = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $GetCredentials -Name "GetCred ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCompilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

Comment: what do you mean get credentials? Why not do the whole thing in powershell. Why use the C# at all

Comment: From the error message it looks like the `$` is causing the issue in your type definition.  What happens if you remove this?  The code inside the type definition should be C#, not PowerShell, so the `$` isn't going to work as a variable signifier.  In a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357542/msgbox-in-powershell-script-run-from-task-scheduler-not-working/54362903#54362903) I do something similar.

Comment: @boxdog `$` isn't valid in a C# variable name.  I agree with ArcSet here, the OP should just use `Get-Credential`.  I feel like this is a XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok So lets talk about whats wrong

```
[DllImport("C:\\Path\\BinaryName.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCredentials", ExactSpelling=false)]
public static extern int GetCredentials([out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] out String $args1, [out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] out String $args2, [In] String $args3);
```

We first get the error for $.

The reason is this happens is you are compiling c# code. and in c# this `$` isnt acceptable param name.

What we can do is take your c# DLLImport

```
[DllImport("BinaryName.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCredentials")]
static extern int GetCredentials(StringBuilder sbUser, StringBuilder sbPassword, string sKey);
```

We will modify this to work by calling full names on the string builders and then making the GetCredentials a Public method

```
[DllImport("BinaryName.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCredentials")]
public static extern int GetCredentials(System.Text.StringBuilder sbUser, System.Text.StringBuilder sbPassword, string sKey);
```

So the whole code should look like

```
$args1 = ""
$args2 = ""
$args3 = "KeyValue"
$GetCredentials = @'
[DllImport("BinaryName.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCredentials")]
public static extern int GetCredentials(System.Text.StringBuilder sbUser, System.Text.StringBuilder sbPassword, string sKey);
'@
$typeFunc = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $GetCredentials -Name "GetCredential" -PassThru -Namespace System.Runtime.InteropServices
$ret = $typeFunc::GetCredentials($args1, $args2, $args3)
```