# Popup dialog from server to remote computer in local network

Tags: c#, powershell, local-network

I'm trying to popup a dialog with some questions from a local network server 
and receive the users answers, something like a winforms window, using c#.
Are there any recommendations for a way of doing this?

Comment: I dont see a Question. Check this link out [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Did you tried something that you can show us? It looks like you are new and i would recommend a simple UDP connection. Just build up a server that is accepting answers from IP's and sending Questions.

Comment: nothing should be installed on client side.

Comment: Running commands remotely is 'easy', but interacting with the desktop to show a popup is likely to be an issue for (valid) security reasons.  You can get limited interactivity with the [Terminal Service API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/).  See, for example, a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357542/msgbox-in-powershell-script-run-from-task-scheduler-not-working/54362903#54362903).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was using PsExec tools.

```
var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "path of psExec",
                Arguments = $"psexec -i -s  \\\\{machineName} {path}",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };

        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();`
```