# How do I use Powershell Invoke-Command?

Tags: windows, powershell, notifications, invoke-command

I use this code to generate a notification:

```
Invoke-Command  -ComputerName comp01 -ScriptBlock {Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;$global:balmsg = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon;$balmsg.BalloonTipTitle = "Title" ;$path = (Get-Process -id $pid).Path;$balmsg.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($path);$balmsg.BalloonTipIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::Warning;$balmsg.BalloonTipText = ‘user';$balmsg.Visible = $true;$balmsg.ShowBalloonTip(20000)}
```

but it doesn't work. When I use this code without Invoke-command, it works properly and shows the notification.

What is wrong?

Comment: Remote commands do not execute in an interactive session, so there is nothing around to pick up the tooltip. There may be none, one or multiple users logged on to a system at any given time, so in general it's not meaningful to go for interactive notifications. You can use something like `msg.exe` to send messages; more complicated stuff requires actually launching commands in other sessions, which is a lot more complicated without external tools like `psexec` to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i need some notification like which this script do, not a massage Box and users must click OK ...., if it have any solution to run this script please describe it

Comment: What should happen if more than one user is logged in, as per Remote Desktop Sessions? What should happen if no users are logged in at all, should the notification be shown later or is it OK if nothing is shown? Can you use third-party tools like `psexec` or `serviceui` or does the solution have to be pure PowerShell? These things determine what kind of solution to aim for. Be aware that none of the approaches will be simple; non-interactive commands are shielded from interactive sessions as a security measure, and overcoming this barrier requires significant effort.

Comment: Take a look at the Terminal Services API which can send messages to specific users/sessions on remote systems.  Here is an example from a previous answer of mine that will give you of what I mean, though it's designed to only work on the local system and will need extended: [TS API Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357542/msgbox-in-powershell-script-run-from-task-scheduler-not-working/54362903#54362903)

Comment: Thank you again jeroen and boxdog, i want a notification shows on clients computer and if client is not logged on, dont show anything , its all of thing i want from this script. How i can run run an interactive command for all of users logged in the target computer ! ? can i use script file or any other solutions !?