# PsExec copy script and run on remote computer

Tags: powershell, psexec

I am trying to show an confirmation-box on a remote computer and from what I understand I can't use invoke-command for any interactive scripts.

I found some tips in a forum-post that I need to run PsExec to be able to run interactive scripts.

I managed to get the script running on a remote host by using:

```
PsExec \\<Host> -s -i powershell -WindowStyle Hidden c:\temp\test.ps1
```

But that just works if the script is already in "c:\temp\test.ps1" on the remote host. I have tried using:

```
PsExec \\<host> -i -s powershell.exe -c c:\dev\scripts\test.ps1 test.ps1
```

and different variations of the "c" and "f" parameters but I only get a flashing black window on the remote host when I run the command from my server. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you just want a simple message box with, say yes/no options, you can try using the Terminal Service API from PowerShell (e.g. using `Invoke-Command`).  Here is an example from a previous answer of mine:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357542/msgbox-in-powershell-script-run-from-task-scheduler-not-working/54362903#54362903

Comment: Wow, I have no clue how that works but it was exactly as I wanted. Thanks.