# PowerShell use of [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox] or [System.Windows.MessageBox]

Tags: windows, powershell

I've been beating my head against a wall for hours trying to figure out how to use either of these message box options to prompt the logged in user for a reboot after a scripted task in PowerShell.  The code I am using below for each option.  If I omit the last two values, the box seems to come up fine unless the script is started by a system account.

I found the "MessageBoxOptions" functionality which appears to be what I want.  However I keep getting stuck on the MessageBoxResult and MessageBoxDefaultButton (Forms) values which appear to be required when using in PowerShell.  No matter what I specify here, the box is never displayed.  It's like it is setting the users option for them.  For the life of me I can't get this command to complete using MessageBoxOptions and trying to omit MessageBoxResult and MessageBoxDefaultButton (Forms).

Ps..  If there is any way for this box to timeout if no option is selected after x period of time, that would be great.  I am not a developer, just a sys admin using PowerShell.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox.show?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-messagebox-show(system-string-system-string-system-windows-messageboxbutton-system-windows-messageboximage-system-windows-messageboxresult-system-windows-messageboxoptions)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
$msgBoxInput =  [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Software has been deployed to your computer by CompanyName IT, please reboot to complete. Select "Yes" to reboot now.  Or if you want to reboot yourself later, select "No".','CompanyName IT','YesNo','Information','none','ServiceNotification')

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$msgBoxInput = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Software has been deployed to your computer by CompanyName IT, please reboot to complete. Select "Yes" to reboot now.  Or if you want to reboot yourself later, select "No".','CompanyName IT','YesNo','Information','Button1','ServiceNotification')
```

Comment: "*the box seems to come up fine unless the script is started by a system account.*" - system accounts can't show GUI elements, that's never going to work. Like you can't enter a PSSession to a remote computer and open notepad and see it appear, it's just blocked by the way Windows works since UAC came in a decade ago.

Comment: I think you might be mistaken here.   ——— https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messageboxoptions?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: You can use the Terminal Services API to send messages to different sessions (even different machines).  Have a look at this example and see if it helps:  [Msgbox in PowerShell script run from task scheduler not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357542/msgbox-in-powershell-script-run-from-task-scheduler-not-working/54362903#54362903)

Comment: @user11221802 could be, could be, but what about [this message](https://i.imgur.com/JRe0L0i.png) which is exlpained here https://helpdesk.kaseya.com/hc/en-gb/articles/229039788-Windows-displays-A-program-running-on-this-computer-is-trying-to-display-a-message-Dialog-box ? System processes run in a different desktop from the user console.

Comment: @user11221802, note that the options relate to a _service_ displaying the message box, which isn't necessarily the same as the system account doing it.

Comment: If a service can pop this box for an interactive session, that’s exactly what I want.  Just need to get syntax right.  The terminal server message isn’t a great option.  I need the user to be able to select yes or no and act on the choice using CMD or PowerShell.

Comment: Anyone try these commands yet?  Just run it from PowerShell and omit the last two comma’d sections..  it’s the default option that gets you.